# I would like to replace NA in a table with the previous non-NA value and "Unclassified_"

Tags: r

Using R: I need to fill any NA cells with the closest value to the Left and also "unclassified_"

The below code works perfectly to fill w/ the closest values to the left but I don't know how to put the permanent string "Unclassified_" before

```
library(zoo)
y <-  t(na.locf(t(x), fromLast=F)) #Fill NA cells with closest value to the left
```

Example Data

```
set.seed(1)
x <- data.frame(a=sample(c(1,2), 10, replace=T),
                b=sample(c(1,2,NA), 10, replace=T), 
                c=sample(c(1:5,NA), 10, replace=T))
```

Gives the df:

```
a   b   c
2   NA  1       
2   2   1       
1   NA  5       
1   1   2       
1   1   NA      
1   NA  4       
1   1   5       
2   2   NA      
2   2   NA      
1   NA  2
```

And I want:

```
a       b            c
2   unclassifed_2    1      
2   2                1      
1   unclassifed_1    5      
1   1                2      
1   1                unclassified_1     
1   unclassified_1   4      
1   1                5      
2   2                unclassified_2     
2   2                unclassified_2         
1   unclassified_1   2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use paste, and index.   this loop does it

```
for( i in 1:ncol(x)){

if( any( is.na(  x[, i ]))){
x[ is.na( x[ , i ] )  , i ] <- 
    paste0( "unclassified_", x[ is.na( x[ , i ] )  , i-1 ] )
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
x$b[is.na(x$b)] = paste0("unclassifed_", x$a)
x$c[is.na(x$c)] = paste0("unclassifed_", x$a)
```

Comment: Your question is more complicated than my answer. I will try to revise it later.